# Efficiently Filtering results by Distance with Linq / EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following:

```
var closeProfiles = (from p in profiles
                    let geo = new GeoCoordinate{Latitude = p.LocationLat, Longitude =  p.LocationLong}
                    where geo.GetDistanceTo(coord) < distance
                    select p);
var results = closeProfiles.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastOnline).Skip(query.Index*40).Take(40).ToList();
```

This returns the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double
>   GetDistanceTo(System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Based on this question:  [C# - LINQ - shortest distance by GPS latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402742/c-sharp-linq-shortest-distance-by-gps-latitude-and-longitude)

I was expecting this to work.  How can I get this working without having to put all profiles into memory before the computation?

Even with the following:

```
var closeProfiles =
                    profiles.Where(e => (((e.LocationLat - coord.Latitude)*(e.LocationLat - coord.Latitude) +
                                          (e.LocationLong - coord.Longitude)*(e.LocationLong - coord.Longitude)) <
                                         distance)).ToList();
```

I get performance similar to:

```
closeProfiles = profiles.ToList()
                        .Where(
                            s =>
                                DistanceUtilities.GetDistance(s.LocationLat, s.LocationLong, user.LocationLat,
                                    user.LocationLong) < user.SearchRadius).ToList();
```

Which is just throwing everything in memory and then doing the computation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cant make Linq compare geodistances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362724/i-cant-make-linq-compare-geodistances)

Comment: And again check the link. :)

Comment: @NikolayKostov the performance implementing the dup's solution is the same as me ToList()ing and then applying a custom Distance function.